# Changing exe Icon from C++ Executable

Tags: c++, windows, icons, exe

I just had an totally crazy Idea: I want to write an Icon changer. The User can select an exe file and the icon which the new exe file should have. The Project should be in c++, but now my question is: Is it possible to change to Icon of an external exe file without recompiling and how can I do it? I've found nothing on the Internet about it, maybe I searched the wrong thing... Can someone please tell me how I can solve the problem?

Comment: An icon that Explorer shows is a resource within the executable. See [`EnumResourceNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648037.aspx), [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx) et al.

Comment: While possible, this will invalidate digital signatures and may set off the anti-virus protection.

Comment: Okay, @IgorTandetnik, can you post it as Answer, so I can mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article may help
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635384/Target-Eye-Revealed-The-Cover-Story
It explains how to locate a certain icon and when you locate the old icon, you can replace it with a new one.